# Alternating Columns on a Array Formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet where data is spread in alternated columns. Columns A, C and E are flags indicating if the adjacent column has a valid data.

It is like this:

```
     A    B   C    D   E    F
1    1   32   0   67   1   34
```

The goal is to sum values where its left adjacent is 1. In this example, the sum should be 66, as A and E are both 1 and C is 0.

I can get an array with 1's and 0's indicating if a flag column is set or not:

```
=MOD(COLUMN(A1:F1),2)*A1:F1
```

And that gives me

> {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}

The thing is that I don't know what I can do from here. If I could slide all the data (by inserting a 0 at the beginning and removing the 0 at the last position), I could SUMPRODUCT it and get the result.

By the way, I can't use macros...

Ideas?

Comment: I know you are showing data in row 1, I assume that's just an example - do you have headers in the real data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that Formula bellow has two cell ranges one starts at column `A` the other at `B`.

```
=SUMIF(A1:F1,1,B1:G1)
```

If you are not famliar with `SUMIF` then what you need to know about this is that first term `A1:F1` is where formula checks values for a condition. What condition you might ask values that equal to seconds term in this case `=1`. Lastly last term has the values that need to be sumed.

Also since you may have issuse of having 1 in an Even column( where you'd expect value not you condition), heve is a formula that makes sure that your 1 & 0 condition is in correct Column:

```
=SUM(IF((A1:F1=1)*ISODD(COLUMN(A1:F1)),B1:G1,0))
```

Comment: That's brilliant! I'm very familiar with SUMIF, but I have never thought about deliberately skipping the first column so that the last one is empty. Amazing!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple version:

```
=SUM(A1*B1,C1*D1,E1*F1)
```

As `0` multiplied by anything is always zero then this only sums the columns preceded by a `1`.

Comment: That's a perfect answer, but I can't do that as I ended the example at F column just for simplicity as, in reality, it goes all the way up to JMB!! (Don't ask me why..)

Comment: Up to `JMB`...wow! Use `spg667` answer with the `sumif`. I upvoted it as it is great answer.